# Binary XML file line #41: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: java, android, xml

hey guys i'm working on a android app when the button equtime is pressed it should open Moainstallerview.java but when I test the app the app crashes :( logcat gives this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.d4a.stz/jp.yhonda.MOAInstallerActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #41: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

heres my code:

```
moainstallerview.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MOAInstallerActivity" >

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Equation Time on Android installs additional 85MB of data. Please                 choose the install location and press Install." />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Internal Storage" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="External Storage (SD Card)" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <!-- Push the button bar to the bottom -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <!-- Divider above the button bar -->
    <View style="?attr/buttonBarDividerStyle" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="?attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equtime"
            style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Install" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i'm getting upset so any help would be amazing i'm a android rookie so please don't judge

Regards

Rapsong11

Answer (score 2):

The error message says "Binary XML file line #41: You must supply a layout_width attribute."

Line 41 is the below one. Your `View` tag here needs to have the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes:

```
<View style="?attr/buttonBarDividerStyle" />
```

For example:

```
<View android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     style="?attr/buttonBarDividerStyle" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, you need to add a layout_width attribute to your buttonBarDividerStyle view.

Try this:

```
<View style="?attr/buttonBarDividerStyle" android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Comment: This isn't enough. This will only cause an error message that layout_height is needed too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, inside one of my layout.xml files, I had

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_1_col_0"
    android:layout_width="@string/default_picture_size"
    android:layout_height="@string/default_picture_size"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/tile"
    android:onClick="mClickMethod" >
</ImageView>
```

and inside strings.xml, I had 
wrap_content

and so it was showing this in Android Studio:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_1_col_0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/tile"
    android:onClick="mClickMethod" >
</ImageView>
```

I thought everything would work because there were no errors and the application compiled and ran. However, there was a run time error that said I didn't set the layout_width.

Once I changed layout_width and layout_height from

```
android:layout_width="@string/default_picture_size"
android:layout_height="@string/default_picture_size"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I defined size without `dp` in dimens.xml:

```
<dimen name="some_width">100</dimen>
```

(Error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in app.package.name/fragment_layout: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #25: You must supply a layout_width attribute.)